# Не устанавливается редактор wysiwig

Tags: phpbb, html, php

Доброго времени суток всем, я нашел отличный редактор, но когда ставлю его на сайт, он не хочет работать, то есть текстбокс не меняется на редактор, а так и остается самим собой, адреса к ява скриптам прописаны правильно, редактор называется  WysiBB, а ошибку пишет Object [object object] has no method 'wysibb' не знаю, что делать, прошу помощи, причем ставил и другие редакторы, тоже не хотели работать.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1) Возможно визуальный редактор не может найти textarea.

1.1) Скачиваешь FireBug

1.2) Находишь в исходном коде тег textarea и смотришь, есть ли у него id или class. Если их нет - то по идее можно найти в исходных кодах сайта, где формируется textarea и самостоятельно проставить для него id или class.

```
<textarea id="i1" class="c2"></textarea>
```

1.3) Прописываешь следующий код. У одной из трёх строк убери в начале //. Это зависит от того, для каких именно textarea ты хочешь применить редактор.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#i1').wysibb(); //id=i1
    //$('.c2').wysibb(); //class=c2
    //$('textarea').wysibb(); //для всех тегов textarea
})
</script>
```

Вариант 2) Либо можно сохранить ту страницу и постепенно удалять лишний код твоего сайта, не относящийся к работе визуального редактора.

Comment: в том и дело что текстфареа есть и у него есть класс, в скрипте класс тоже верно объявлен, но бестолку (( не понимаю почему

Comment: Возьми демо-версию с визуальным редактором. И постепенно добавляй код, который у тебя на сайте. Может проблема в разных версиях Jquery

Comment: ладно, спасибо, попробую разобраться ((